# Getting data from API into Microsoft flow

Tags: power-automate

My task is to get data from business central into Microsoft flow through API's of that user who trigger the flow in business central.
but when I trigger flow from business central it gives me all the data of all users from business central. but again I just want to get the data of that specific user into Microsoft flow.
can anyone please guide

Comment: Show us your flow and provide more detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.